# How to leverage IApplicationLifecycleAware

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Can someone point me to an example of how to leverage IApplicationLifecycleAware for Prism and Xamarin.Forms? I have a view model that implements it but OnResume and OnSleep never fire (although it fires within my App.xaml.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `IApplicationLifecycleAware` you simply need to implement it on any ViewModel you wish to use it, and add the code to the OnSleep and OnResume methods that you require.

It is very important though that if you implement an override of these methods in your App class that you include the base execution otherwise the PrismApplication cannot execute the IApplicationLifecycleAware methods on the ViewModel of your current page.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle IApplicationLifecycle
        base.OnSleep();

        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle IApplicationLifecycle
        base.OnResume();

        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. I had the base call already. However, I didn't realize this only fires on the active page's ViewModel. Makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: The assumption is that when you've navigated away from some View you've already done anything you may need to do for Sleep so you should only really need to handle this on the current view.